# Different ways to rectify Vasthu dosha?

Tags: vastu-shastra

If there is any Vasthu dosha then the learned people tell to get the things proper by renovating or rectifying on contructional level.

So to rectify Vasthu dosha , can Yagnas, Veda chanting would help ?

Comment: [Related not Duplicate] [What is the mythological origin of Vastu?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14927/3500)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So to rectify Vasthu dosha , can Yagnas, Veda chanting would help ?

Yes,One can recite the following Suktam from Rig Veda to pacify Vastu Purusha and lessen the effects of Vastu Dosha:

> Vasthoshpathe is the God who protects residencial buildings. As soon
>   as a building is built he occupies it. So immediately after a house is
>   built, the guardian of the house should be made happy, this prayer in
>   the Rig Veda is addressed to this guardian

Few verses from the [Vastu Suktam](http://www.bharatiweb.com/wp-content/uploads/Vastu-Sooktam-Eng-v11.pdf) are given below:

> *Vasthoshpathe prathi jaanhihyasman, Thsvaveso aanamivo bhavaa na, Yath thwameha prathi thanno jushaswa, Sham no bhava dwipade sham
>   chathushpade.,*

Meaning-

> Oh protector of the dwelling, please know us, Make this home good for
>   us and free from ills, Please grant us what we seek from you, Make us
>   who are two legged and four legged[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sri_Yantra) happy

&

> Ameevahaa Vasthishpathe, Vishwa roopani avishaan, Sakhaa Suseva yedi
>   na.,

Meaning-

> Oh guardian of the house, remove all ills from here, By taking al
>   forms of the universe, And be my friend and provide us good service.

You can read and understand the full Suktam from [here](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Vaasthu_Manthras):

Also Lord Shiva is the Vastu Pati.So if you make him happy the Vastu problems will automatically get nullified gradually.That is why it is recommended that one acquires a Swaymabhu manifestation of Shiva called the [Banalinga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banalinga) or Narmadeswara linga and place it the north east corner of the house(also known as the Ishana direction).

> ***Vaastoshpatey*** Pinaakaaya Muktaye Kevalaayacha, Mrigavyaadhaaya Dakshaaya Sthaanavey Bhishanaayacha/ (**The Principal Founder of
>   Vaastu Shastra**; The distinguished Wearer of Pinaka Dhanush; The
>   Bestower of Salvation; The Singular and Unique Purusha...)(from Shiva
>   Astottara found in Linga Purana)

And,since by worshiping a [Sri Yantra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sri_Yantra) all Gods are getting worshiped one can also acquire a properly energised Sri Yantra and worship it daily.

So,in case when reconstruction is not possible,the methods given above can be employed to reduce the effects of Vastu Dosha.

Comment: Great! Thanks brother you have been really helpful.

Comment: No problems bro,i only share whatever little i know.I'm glad to know  that my posts have helped you.:)