# Did Feng Shui originate from Hinduism?

Tags: scripture, vedas, puranas, vastu-shastra

Feng Shui is the concept of living in harmony with nature and is used for constructions mainly in China and western countries.
Vaastu shastra is the Hindu system of construction and its origin has been described in Matsya Purana.

More information about origin of Vastu can be found here: [What is the mythological origin of Vastu?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14927/13242)

My question is whether Feng Shui has been derived from vastu shastra and if so:

1.Are there any proofs or records available to support this claim?

2.Are the Gods mentioned in Feng Shui originally from Hinduism,e.g Gods of Wealth Fuk Luk Sau?

Comment: I think they both might have developed independently based on similar principles. Moreover, this question requires speculative analysis which might get it closed.